# remove duplicates faster vb6

Tags: vb6

i have this function which is slow in removing duplicates in vb6

```
Function FilterDuplicates(Arr As Variant) As Long
    Dim col      As Collection, index As Long, dups As Long
    Set col = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next

    For index = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        ' build the key using the array element
        ' an error occurs if the key already exists
        col.Add 0, CStr(Arr(index))
        If Err Then
            ' we've found a duplicate
            Arr(index) = Empty
            dups = dups + 1
            Err.Clear
        ElseIf dups Then
            ' if we've found one or more duplicates so far
            ' we need to move elements towards lower indices
            Arr(index - dups) = Arr(index)
            Arr(index) = Empty
        End If
    Next

    ' return the number of duplicates
    FilterDuplicates = dups

End Function
```

I need to optimize this function to run faster, please help

Comment: I updated my answer to add the final bit.  I have to ask though, was this a homework assignment?

Comment: no it is not homework, but why did you ask that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function FilterDuplicates(Arr As Variant) As Long
    Dim col      As Dictionary, index As Long, dups As Long
    Set col = New Dictionary

    On Error Resume Next

    For index = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        ' build the key using the array element
        ' an error occurs if the key already exists
        If col.Exists(Arr(index)) Then
            ' we've found a duplicate
            dups = dups + 1
        Else
            Call col.Add(Arr(index), vbNullstring)
        End If
    Next

    Dim newArr(1 to col.Keys.Count) As Variant
    Dim newIndex As Long
    For index = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        If col(Arr(index)) = vbNullstring Then
            newIndex = newIndex + 1
            col(Arr(index)) = "Used"
            newArr(newIndex) = Arr(index)
        End If
    Next index
    Arr = newArr

    ' return the number of duplicates
    FilterDuplicates = dups

End Function
```

Comment: the function is not complete, how do i use it then?

Comment: Two things.  First, you have to add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to your project using the Project/References dialog so you can use the Dictionary.  Second, there's a `Then` missing on the `If col.Exists...` line.  As far as it being incomplete, all it's missing is the rebuild of the array excluding those items that exist in `col` once the For/Next is complete.  You can handle that, I would think...?  Hint: another For/Next loop?

Comment: instead of using collection, can't i just use ordinary array?

Comment: @Oghenero - I thought you wanted it to be fast.  A Dictionary is based on a hash table, so it has O(1) lookup time.  Therefore, finding duplicates is fast.  To find a duplicate in an array, it has to scan the array, which is an O(n) operation.  Since you have to do the duplicates check inside a loop, the full Dictionary based solution is O(n) and the array based solution would be O(n^2) - which is bad.

Comment: @Oghenero - the Dictionary is an implementation of a hash table.  I think "How do I implement a hashtable in VB6?" would be its own question.  But I'll help you with that: http://tinyurl.com/5ukx755

Answer (score 0):

using String concatenation (not too fast with a large array) and InStrB() function:

```
Function FilterDuplicates(arr As Variant) As Long
Dim item As String, dups As Long, strArray As String

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    item = arr(i)
    If lenb(item) <> 0 Then
      If InStrB(1, strArray, item) = 0 Then
        strArray = strArray & item & ";"
      Else
        dups = dups + 1
      End If
    End If
Next i

FilterDuplicates = dups
End Function
```